# My Bose headphones (both QCII and Soundsport) have an echo

Tags: headphones, bose

I have no idea what to do to fix this issue.  When I search for Bose and Echo, I get a ton of articles on how to connect Bose headphones to Amazon Echo.  I don't want that.

Both sets of my headphones have a slight delay.  Like, milliseconds. But it's crazy annoying.  This only seems to happen with AppleTV+.  At least as far as I have noticed.

Has anyone else had this happen?  This is the 2nd laptop that has this issue.  I have another laptop that does NOT have this issue.

Comment: Audio delay over Bluetooth is standard.  Some applications delay the video by enough time for the audio to have been encoded, sent to the receiving headphones, decoded and then played but some applications don't take it into account. The result is some applications having a "weird audio delay". It's just something you have to deal with or get headphones that specifically state "low latency". Bluetooth sucks for pretty much everything except music and even there it's quality is questionable due to patchy codec support on either side.

Comment: That stinks.  Thank you, though.  I need to get some princess Leia headphones that are wired so I don't have to get annoyed.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but I managed to fix it.
Heres how:
I went into System > Sound > Properties
and switched "Audio Enhancements" from "Device default Effects" to "OFF" and it's fixed. The difference was much greater than I even imagined. Its not clear what the Device default Effects were, but they were causing problems.

[See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlNmb.png)
Note: My problem was also with a Bose QCII but it was clearly not bluetooth related as it was happening when they were plugged in. It sounded like a very slight flange effect.